# Load library dynamically depending on settings

Tags: 8, theming

My theme has a few settings that can be adjusted, one of them is style.

I want to load the libraries depending on the styles, but without writing them in the `.libraries.yml`

```
function my_theme_library_info_build() {
  $libraries = [];

  return $libraries;
}

function my_theme_library_info_alter(&$libraries, $extension) {
  $tmp_theme = theme_get_setting( 'my_theme' );

  $libraries['my_theme.theme']['css']['theme'] = [
      'css/themes/' . $tmp_theme . '.min.css' => [],
  ];
}
```

This is what I've got so far but I have to clear the cache after changing the style.

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do here. But I reckon there's a different way to do it that doesn't involve cache clearing.

Comment: @Beebee I've had it like it that the library got attached in `hook_preprocess_html` but that required them to be added in the `libraries.yml`. My Theme is iterating through the style files and is showing those in the settings to be selected. Now I only need them to be dynamically loaded so that I can add/delete them without changing any other file.

Comment: Given your theme setting is a dropdown, you'll have to write code anyway. Just to make sure: Why don't you want to create separate libraries for each of your "theme"?

Comment: I would have to add every style manually to the `libraries.yml` and I want to skip this step so that I can add or delete files without changing any other file.

Comment: Then I'd reckon, that your current version is the best you can do. Rebuilding the caches after changing your styles would be required anyway, so that Drupal won't deliver already cached pages with your old styles.

Comment: I have created patch for this please check
https://www.drupal.org/project/social_icons/issues/2984954

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this slightly differently. What you can do is combine all the different style css files into one, and use a className prefix instead of a file name prefix. So instead of having `foo.min.css` and `bar.min.css` you'll have 1 css file that's always included but has `body.foo {}` and `body.bar {}`  styles in them.

Of course this gets easier with a preprocessor such as SASS: for every element you want to style you can wrap it in their respective `body.foo` or `body.bar` parents, without having to manually write `body.foo` in front of every element you want to style. So I highly recommend you use something like SASS for this, but it's not required at all.

The advantage of this method is *I think* it avoids problems with caching different CSS files since you're using only one. Also if your original goal of having separate CSS files was to keep them neat and separate then you can do that with your SASS files and they can be compiled into a minified single CSS file by your SASS processor.

Comment: The page would load slower and slower the more styles/themes are added. So instead of loading a single 200kb stylesheet, it would load a 1mb stylesheet if 5 themes are added, 2mb if 10 themes are added and so on.

Comment: @Kazuto – 1 MB styles. That's huge. Let me remind you: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. In the end you switch JS/CSS aggregation on and move on.

Comment: The style itself has 200kb before aggregation. It's already minified and such. But if I combine 5 styles it would have 1mb but not a single style itself.

Comment: @Kazuto 1MB css stylesheet definitely changes things, it would for me. Looking at the comments, if you don't want to add things to libraries.yml then I don't think there's many other ways. If you are willing to do this extra step, then you can play around with the render array, and change the loaded library instead, which can get around caching issues.